# Calculate average of non numeric columns in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a df "data" as below

```
Name    Quality city
Tom     High    A
nick    Medium  B
krish   Low     A
Jack    High    A
Kevin   High    B
Phil    Medium  B
```

I want group it by city and a create a new columns based on the column "quality" and calculate avegare as below

```
 city  High Medium Low High_Avg Medium_AVG Low_avg
 A    2      0     1    66.66       0      33.33
 B    1      1     0     50         50        0
```

I tried with the below script and I know it is completely wrong.
data_average = data_df.groupby(['city'], as_index = False).count()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a count of the frequencies, divide the outcome by the sum across columns, and finally concatenate the datframes into one :

```
result = pd.crosstab(df.city, df.Quality)
averages = result.div(result.sum(1).array, axis=0).mul(100).round(2).add_suffix("_Avg")
#combine the dataframes
pd.concat((result, averages), axis=1)

Quality High    Low Medium  High_Avg    Low_Avg Medium_Avg
city                        
 A       2       1     0    66.67       33.33   0.00
 B       1       0     2    33.33       0.00    66.67
```